# Is it possible to clobber rails associations with a single table inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a pretty nasty situation with a botched implementation of single table inheritance. What I want to know is whether the 'descendent' class can clobber the association of its 'parent'. I don't think this is the case but I'd like to get confirmation whether I can or not.

Below are the simplified models in question:

```
class CertificateName < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :ssl_account, through: :certificate_content
end

class Domain < CertificateName
  has_one :ssl_account, touch: true
end
```

Here is the schema simplified):

```
create_table "certificate_names", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "certificate_content_id" 
    t.integer  "ssl_account_id"
  end
```

In the scenario above, does the inherited `Domain` class have a direct association with `ssl_account` or would it go through the `CertificateName` model association? Based on what I am seeing I would think that in my case an `ssl_account` has a direct relationship with the model and does not follow the `has_one :through` Thoughts?

Comment: I am assuming `class CertificateName (Parent class)` should be `class CertificateName < ApplicationRecord` and `class Domain (Inheritance class)` should be `class Domain < CertificateName` if so I would recommend editing the post to show this. Also if this is true your migration needs work for STI (e.g. a `*_type` field) and when you add `has_one :ssl_account, touch: true` to `Domain` you are redefining the relationship (not adding to it)

Comment: @engineersmnky so my table doesn't have a type field, which is why its botched. Does that still mean that the Domain model is redefining the relationship still? What Im trying to ask, is will `certificate_name.ssl_account` go through the `certificate_content` model and `domain.ssl_account` go through a direct relationship

Comment: Yes `Domain` has overwritten the `ssl_account` method of its parent in this context. The same as `class A; def hello; 'hi';end;end` and `class B < A; def hello; 'hola';end;end` would result in `A.new.hello #=> "hi"` and `B.new.hello #=> "hola"`

Comment: @engineersmnky a follow up, I understand the theory of how it could be rewritten but wouldnt it have to follow enforced  schema relation structure? This isn't just plain ruby code, it's backed by a table structure. Wouldn't that be problematic?

Comment: Honestly `CertificateName` is the weird class here and I have no idea what the context of `CertificateContent` is as a join. If  "certificate_contents" contains an `ssl_account_id` then the linking would still work appropriately but this is a highly unconventional setup and would make maintainability much more difficult in my opinion. to explain further getting to `SslAccount` from CertificateName would be CertificateName  -> CertificateContent -> SslAccount; from Domain would be Domain (using the "certificate_names" table) -> SslAccount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to clobber rails associations with a single table
>   inheritance?

**Yes.**

When you declare multiple associations with the same name the last evaluated association will always clobber the existing association no matter where it was declared.

The assocations macros (`belongs_to`, `has_one`, `has_many`, `has_and_belongs_to_many`) both generate methods and also an [association reflection](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html) which is simply held in a hash like structure so passing the same key (the name of the assocation) will just clobber it.

```
class Domain < CertificateName
  has_one :ssl_account, touch: true
end
```

Will always join directly to `ssl_accounts` and expect it to have a `certificate_name_id` foreign key column.